# How can I connect a MonoDevelop project to BitBucket using git or svn?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, dvcs, bitbucket

i'm using BitBucket to host my code because I can have a free PRIVATE repository.

Can someone show me the connection details if wish to use MonoDevelop to connect to bitbuck via git, svn please? I'm under the impression that HG is not support in MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab your https link from the overview page on bitbucket.org (once you've logged in)

From MonoDevelop:

1. Go to Version control and "Checkout"
2. Make sure you have the `Protocol` set to HTTPS
3. Put your https link in the `Url:` spot and it will auto-fill everything for you.
4. Make sure your target directory is correct. I just created a new folder in my `Projects` directory called "Repository"
5. Click "OK" and enter your credentials when it asks (it should prefill your username)
6. The version control drop-down should now allow you to publish your changes (after you enter your credentials that is)

Let me know if this helps

Comment: you must have git installed for the above solution to work. Now in Xcode that requires you to have the xcode command line tools for your version of Mac before trying to install git.

Answer (score 2):

Look here on how you can use Git and have a free private Hg repo on BitBucket - http://quirkygba.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-use-bitbuckets-free-private.html

Comment: Interesting .. but that's all command line stuff. I'm hoping to leverage the integrated stuff in MonoDevelop without having to use terminal to push/pull. (and please, not comments about UI vs command line, etc).